# Set Up Git for SSHFS Remote Directory

Tags: linux, git, ssh-keys, sshfs

I am trying to set up an infrastructure where a server folder is mapped into a local directory using SSHFS. This local directory, then, serves as the project folder for Eclipse/Aptana. I would like to be able to work on this project and then push the changes to remote, when needed (from my local machine).

The problem I am having is setting up the SSH keys. Namely, should there be 2 keys (local and server where the original SSHFS source is located) or just one? If there is only one key that was made on the server, will my local machine be able to use it somehow through SSHFS?

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: This setup is going to be really painful if you have a lot of files in eclipse. Its better to do a save on upload and do all your git and file editing locally.

Comment: Do you mean download and upload everything through Git? That is, use Github as the connection between the server and my local machine?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your setup. Are you are coding locally, then deploying through sshfs?

Comment: Basically, I often need to do some small changes that do not always warrant opening a whole new branch and pushing/pulling. What I was trying to do is set up 

(^) Github <-> Server <-(via SSHFS) -> Local -> Github (^)
where, Github (^) - indicates the same repository.


The Server-Local connection is just to allow for easy making of small changes.